# Using two variables inside and out of tkinter after the mainloop()

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am an amateur programmer who is very new to python and this is my tkinter project. I am trying to create a GUI script to enter two numeric values in a file using tkinter. These values must be non-negative float of integers and first value has to be bigger than the second. The problem is when I use .get() method to get the values within the mainloop() it seems to print them correctly but I am unable to do any comparisons of the values within or outside the mainloop(). Also, after the mainloop() the variables have no values in them.
Ideal output of the code will be that it doesn't come out of the mainloop till TSS>VSS (user keeps entering values till the condition is met) and I get the inputs in two different variables i.e. valVSS and valTSS that I can use later.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()  # Create Root Window
root.title("Virtual Sieve Inputs - Screen 2")  # Popup screen title
root.geometry("900x900")  # Screen Dimensions

# Create Variables for later to get the data out.
valTSS = StringVar()
valVSS = StringVar()
# Assigning default values to the variables
valTSS.set(0.2)
valVSS.set(0.1)

def TSS():
  num = (my_boxTSS.get())
  try:
    valTSS = float(num)  #Accepts an float or integer
    answer.config(text='That is a valid TSS number')
    print(valTSS)
  except ValueError:
    answer.config(text='Please enter a valid number for TSS')

def VSS():
  num = (my_boxVSS.get())
  #my_boxVSS.quit()
  try:
    valVSS = float(num)  #Accepts an float or integer
    answer1.config(text='That is a valid VSS number')
    print(valVSS)
  except ValueError:
    answer1.config(text='Please enter a valid number for VSS')


my_labelTSS = Label(root, text="Enter TSS value in mg/L :")
my_labelTSS.pack(pady=20)
my_boxTSS= Entry(root)
my_boxTSS.pack(pady=10)
my_buttonTSS= Button(root, text="Enter TSS value in mg/L", command=TSS)
my_buttonTSS.pack(pady=5)
answer=Label(root, text='')
answer.pack(pady=20)

my_labelVSS = Label(root, text="Enter VSS value in mg/L :")
my_labelVSS.pack(pady=20)
my_boxVSS= Entry(root)
my_boxVSS.pack(pady=10)
my_buttonVSS= Button(root, text="Enter VSS value in mg/L", command=VSS)
my_buttonVSS.pack(pady=5)
answer1=Label(root, text='')
answer1.pack(pady=20)


#ideally following two lines should show up only when (valTSS)>(valVSS). Until the condition is met, the user should be prompted to enter values
 
next_button = Button(root, text="Next", command=root.destroy) # escape the mainloop only when the condition is met
next_button.pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()

print('\n',valTSS,valVSS) # so valTSS and valVSS could be used later in the code
```

Answer (score 0):

The code outside root.mainloop() will only execute after the Tkinter window is terminated. move the print above root.mainloop()

```
print('\n',valTSS,valVSS)
root.mainloop()
```